# Search Results Sorting through Querystring

Tags: 2013, search-results, query-string

I followed [this](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/) post on creating a Company Directory which uses the Sort Dropdown in the Search Results Web Part. This is great but is there any way to do this through manipulating the Query string? I know with list views you can alter the Query string to Sort and Filter the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can manipulated the sorting in the query string like this:

```
https://site/search/results.aspx#Default={"k":"SearchWord","o":[{"d":0,"p":"ManagedProperty"}]}
```

I'm sure you can do more advanced sorting as well, here is a good reference: [Sort search results](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/01/09/how-to-sort-search-results-by-query-string-with-the-resultscriptwebpart-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)